# Consistency of Theory and Deduction Theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory, proof-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a consistent theory of propositional logic and $\varphi$ a propositional formula.

It is well known that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is consistent if $\Gamma \not\vdash \varphi$.

A common procedure for proving this is to exploit deduction theorem. My question is, is there any way to show the consistency of $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ without using deduction theorem?

In other words, is it impossible to show the consistency of $\Gamma$ in a logic system where the deduction theorem does not hold? (Note that the completeness theorem is also not yet proven.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that even though your language is propositional, your *logic* $L$ is non-classical. Why? Because the deduction theorem fails as per the condition of your question.

In general, if you do not have the deduction theorem, you cannot say that $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ is consistent iff $\Gamma\not\vdash_L\phi$ even if you have a complete axiomatisation of $L$! You need a suitable *paracomplete* logic.

Consider strong three-valued Kleene logic $\mathbf{K3}$. Its truth values are $\mathbf{t}$ (true), $\mathbf{u}$ (undefined), and $\mathbf{f}$ ordered as follows $\mathbf{t}>\mathbf{u}>\mathbf{f}$. Conjunction and disjunction are the meet and join w.r.t. this order, negation is as follows: $\neg\mathbf{t}=\mathbf{f}$, $\neg\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}$, $\neg\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{t}$. Additionally, we use $\mathbf{u}$ as a propositional constant.

A set of formulas has a model if there is a valuation s.t. all formulas in this set have value $\mathbf{t}$. We also define $\Gamma\models_\mathbf{K3}\phi$ as follows: $v(\phi)=\mathbf{t}$ in every valuation s.t. $v[\Gamma]=\mathbf{t}$.

Now, let $\Gamma=\{p\}$. It is clear that $p\not\models_{\mathbf{K3}}\mathbf{u}$. On the other hand, $p,\neg\mathbf{u}\models_{\mathbf{K3}}q$ and $p,\neg\mathbf{u}\models_{\mathbf{K3}}\neg q$ which makes $\{p,\neg\mathbf{u}\}$ inconsistent, provided you have a complete axiomatisation of $\mathbf{K3}$.

In fact, a simpler counterexample is as follows: $p\not\models_\mathbf{K3}q\vee\neg q$ but $\{p,q\wedge\neg q\}$ is inconsistent.

====

P.S. $\mathbf{K3}$, of course, can be axiomatised. A simple axiomatisation can be found in, e.g., *Hilbert-style axiomatization of first-degree entailment and a family of its extensions* by Shramko (Annals of Pure and Applied Logic, 2022).

====

P.P.S. The OP needs a specific logic, namely, the logic of ortholattices. Its main difference from classical logic is the lack of distributivity laws (which are replaced with orthomodularity properties).

Consider a lattice $\mathbf{M4}$ (a six-element lattice with four midpoints: $\mathbf{a}$, $\neg\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\neg\mathbf{b}$). Again, we can adapt the counterexample for $\mathbf{K3}$: $p\not\models_\mathbf{M4}\mathbf{a}$ but $p,\neg\mathbf{a}\models_\mathbf{M4}\bot$.

Note, however, that in this case, it is essential that you allow constants in your language. Otherwise, you will have the consistency criterion from classical logic. Indeed, it is easy to show by induction on $\phi$ over $\{\neg,\wedge,\vee\}$ that if there is no evaluation s.t. $v_\mathbf{M4}(\phi)=\top$, then $\phi\equiv_\mathbf{M4}\bot$.

To do that, it suffices to check that if there is a valuation $v$ s.t. $v(\phi)=\mathbf{a}$, there is a valuation $v'$ s.t. $v'(\phi)=\top$.

Comment: I am sorry for the poor explanation of the situation. I am thinking of a 2-valued non-classical logic called orthologic, which does not enjoy the deduction theorem. Is there a counterexample for the 2-valued case?

Comment: Could you give a link to the semantics?

Comment: @yue Or do you mean the logic (equational theory, basically) of ortholattices? If the latter is the case, you can use my example: $\mathbf{K3}$ extends the logic of ortholattices.

Comment: Yes, by orthologic I mean the logic of ortholattice. I'll look into your example.

Comment: Oh, wait, $\mathbf{K3}$ does not extend the ortholattice logic. I'll update the example.

Comment: @yue, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I think your example shows no doubt that the consistency of $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is not provable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**A proof by contradiction**:

$1.$ Let $\Gamma$ be a consistent theory. Then, by definition of consistency, there is no formula $\phi \in \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg\phi$. In other words, it is *not* the case there exists a formula $\phi \in \Gamma$ such that $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ are both derivable in $\Gamma$.

$2.$ Assume $\Gamma \not\vdash \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is a formula in propositional logic. In other words, assume the formula $\varphi$ is *not* derivable in $\Gamma$.

$3.$ Now, assume $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is *not* consistent where $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is a theory obtained by simply adding $\neg\varphi$ to the language of $\Gamma$. Then, by definition of consistency, there exists a formula $\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg\phi$. Now, there are two possible cases to consider: that this formula $\phi$ causing $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ to be inconsistent is either in $\Gamma$ or in $\{\neg\varphi\}$.

$4.$ **Case (i)** $\phi \in \Gamma$

If we assume there is a formula $\phi \in \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg\phi$, then we immediately obtain a contradiction because we have already stated in step $1$ that $\Gamma$ is consistent and this cannot be the case.

$5.$ **Case (ii)** $\phi \in \{\neg\varphi\}$

If $\phi \in \{\neg\varphi\}$, then we have $\phi = \neg\varphi$ because $\neg\varphi$ is the only element in $\{\neg\varphi\}$. Hence, $\Gamma \vdash \neg\varphi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg\neg\varphi$, and by the double negation law we may infer $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$. But we have already stated in step $2$ that $\Gamma \not\vdash \varphi$. Thus, once again we obtain a contradiction.

$6$. Under the assumption in step $3$ that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is *not* consistent, we considered two possible cases: that the formula $\phi$ causing $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ to be inconsistent was either in $\Gamma$ or in $\{\neg\varphi\}$. In each case, we obtained a contradiction. Thus, our assumption in step $3$ must be false, implying it must *not* be the case that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is inconsistent. In other words, it must be the case that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is consistent.

$7$. Therefore, if $\Gamma \not\vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is consistent.

Comment: The definition of contradiction is $\exists \phi$ s.t. $\Gamma  \cup \{\neg\varphi\} \vdash \phi$ and $\Gamma  \cup \{\neg\varphi\} \vdash \neg\phi$. But I don't think it needs to be $\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$.

Comment: Since the OP does not have the D.T., their logic is non-classical. I doubt that one can use double negation elimination here.

Comment: @yue $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg\varphi \}$ have the same deductive apparatus. Thus, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ if and only if $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg\varphi \} \vdash \phi$

Comment: @DaniilKozhemiachenko I did not interpret the OP to mean DT was non-existent... only that he wanted to prove without using DT. For instance, if someone wants to prove the integral of a logarithm without integration by parts, this does not mean we have to use an entire system where integration by parts is not derivable and does not exist... it merely means you find a proof within the system that doesn't use integration by parts

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But you would not say that the integration by parts ‘does not hold’, would you?

Comment: @DaniilKozhemiachenko that's a good point. well, if OP doesn't find my response helpful, then he or she can ignore it

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I am thinking of a non-classical logic called orthologic. The logic is 2-valued and double negation is eliminable. I think the point is not that, but that $\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ does not hold (even in the ordinary logic).

Comment: @yue I'm not sure what you mean by saying "$\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ does not hold."  In some places of my proof the expression $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is a reference to a theory; in other places $\Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$ is a reference to the language that results from adding the formula $\neg\varphi$ to the langauge of $\Gamma$. When I write "a formula $\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$," I am using the latter meaning.

Comment: @yue In other words, when I write "a formula $\phi \in \Gamma \cup \{\neg\varphi\}$," I am referenceing an arbitrary formula $\phi$ that is in the language of $\Gamma$ after having added the formula $\neg\varphi$ to the lanaguage of $\Gamma$. This makes complete sense.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Do you mean that $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \varphi\}$ is not just the union of sets, but also contains all formulas proved from it?  If so, we cannot say that either $\phi \in \Gamma$ or $\phi \in \{\neg \varphi\}$ holds...